# Airflow ML Engine Package_URI

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-composer

What is the package URI used for? Is it mandatory? If so how do I create one? 
Currently I have my model package into the proper format of:

```
model.py
task.py
_init_.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're asking about package_uris in MLEngineTrainingOperator.

The instructions about it can be found in [Cloud ML Engine Documentations](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/packaging-trainer).
One thing different is that unlike when using `gcloud`, it is mandatory for Airflow integration that you need to provide/pakcage a package yourself since Airflow operators are running remotely and it cannot package from your local directory.

What you might need here is setup.py based on setuptools, with proper dependencies.
(btw, `_init_.py` is not a valid file, `__init__.py` is.)
When the directories are ready, you can simply run the following command to upload the package.

```
python setup.py sdist 
gsutil cp dist/<tarfile> gs://<your_bucket>/<folder>/
```

Or, if you already have a package that's uploaded using `gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training` command, you can simply provide the uri to reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to [manually build the package](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/packaging-trainer#manual-build) and place it in the Cloud composer bucket. I then supplied the path to the file in the bucket:

```
package_uris=["gs://us-central1-ml-engine/trainer-0.1.tar.gz"]
```